# how can use Full Text Search For Persian Text File In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I Have the Table that contains the **varbinary col** I insert my Text File To it.

I Add Catalog and Full Text Index and I can Search for English Words Successfully like below:

```
select * from [FILESTREAM_Documents]
where Contains([DocumentFS], 'Hello')
```

And I Get Result Correctly As Below:

[image]

I Used this [Doc For getting here](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-filestream-and-sql-server-full-text-search/)

Know My Question is How Can I **Search Persian Word** In **FileStream** Using **Full Text Search** Like Image Below:

```
select * from [FILESTREAM_Documents]
where Contains([DocumentFS], 'سلام')
```

I searched it so much and I test the **(N) Prefix** for the word but still does not work

How can I do this?
Thanks for Helping!

Comment: there are two possibilities and they are sescribed here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177342/fulltext-index-on-varbinary-column-how-to-find-string-with-dot

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/choose-a-language-when-creating-a-full-text-index?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: @Charlieface hi i seen this before i cant found the way for it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: What was the text encoding of the test file you inserted? It doesn't include a Unicode premable/byte order mark, so how will the full-text index filters know that it contains Unicode characters instead of OEM/codepage ones?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning i Check my files , Endocing is UTF-8 as txt file

Comment: @larnu Yes Sir you are right i Fixed It as possible it can be

Comment: The varbinary data in `DocumentFS` is not UTF-8 encoded otherwise it would start with `0xEFBBBF`. Are you absolutely 100% positive that the file was saved with a BOM (Byte Order Mark)? e.g.: in Notepad when going to File > Save as... you would choose `Encoding: UTF-8 with BOM`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning No  idont Encoding UTF-8 With Bom but i test it know And Yes your right my Problem is Solved Thanks

Comment: After Txt File How Can Filter In Xlsx or pdf or Word  and etc files ? Any idea @AlwaysLearning